# send bash stderr to logfile, but only if an error exists

Tags: bash, stderr

I am using the following code to send stderr to a file.

```
.script >2 "errorlog.$(date)"
```

The problem is that a blank log file is created every time I run the script, even if an error doesn't exist. I have looked online and in a few books as well, and can't figure out how to create a log file only if errors exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Output redirection opens the file before the script is run, so there is no way to tell if the file will receive any output. What you can do, however, is immediately delete the file if it winds up being empty:

```
logfile="errorlog.$(date)"
# Note your typo; it's 2>, not >2
script 2> "$logfile"; [ -s "$logfile" ] || rm -f "$logfile"
```

I use `-f` just in case, as `-s` can fail if `$logfile` does not exist, not just if it's empty. I use `;` to separate the commands because whether or not `$logfile` contains anything does not depend on whether or not `script` succeeds.

You can wrap this up in a function to make it easier to use.

```
save_log () {
    logfile=${1:-errorlog.$(date)}
    cat - > "$logfile"
    [ -s "$logfile" ] || rm -f "$logfile"
}

script 2> >( save_log )
script 2> >( save_log my_logfile.txt )
```

Not quite as simple as redirecting to a file, and depends on a non-standard feature (process substitution), but not too bad, either.

Comment: I created a sample script with an error and I used your first example. It successfully creates a new log file each time. It still creates a blank log file when I run the fixed script though, and it doesn't delete the file. Do you think I need to alter the rm part?

Comment: I got it. I wasn't putting ./ in front of $logfile

I used the following to fix it. 

logfile="errorlog.$(date)"
./script 2> "./<dir>/$logfile"; [ -s "./<dir>/$logfile" ] || rm -f "./<dir>$logfile"

I also added sleep in between the creation and deletion of the file to make sure it was working. Thanks for your help chepner!

logfile="errorlog.$(date)"
./script 2> "./<dir>/$logfile"; sleep 2 ; [ -s "./<dir>/$logfile" ] || rm -f "./<dir>/$logfile"

Comment: @chepner "I use -f just in case, as -s can fail if $logfile does not exist, not just if it's empty." Does it not become moot, then? If -s fails because there is no file then rm have no file to delete? Or am I misunderstanding something? Sorry for the necrophilia, but I think the question is valid.

Comment: @pastic `-s` can fail for two reasons: there is no file, and there is a file but it is empty. `rm -f` suppresses the error message in the first case.